# Which Activity Life cycle gets called when app redirect to settings

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, lifecycle

In my application, I am calling gps setting menu if gps is not enabled. I called this in Oncreate() method. However, I also wants to check whether user actually enables it or not?

My Question is which activity life cycle method gets called when user get back from setting menu.

I tried to write code for OnResume method. But alertdilogue keeps poping even GPS is enabled.

```
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        altitude = gps.getAltitude();
        gpsLocation = "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude
                + ",Altitude:" + altitude;
        System.out.println("GPS @ Avaialable Form"+gpsLocation);

        Logger.e(this, "GPS Location", gpsLocation);
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
```

I called this code in OnCreate() and

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("On Resume gets Called");


    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        altitude = gps.getAltitude();
        gpsLocation = "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude
                + ",Altitude:" + altitude;
        System.out.println("GPS @ Avaialable Form"+gpsLocation);

        Logger.e(this, "GPS Location", gpsLocation);
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
```

in OnResume() Method.

Comment: onstyop called when app navigate to settings and when back onresume called if you use startactivityfor resule than onactivity result called

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find out is using the build in caller methods triggered, when one event like on pause() is called, then you log the name of the event, and voila then you know which class is triggered to which time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only reliable way is setup and listen to the gps changes via listener (GpsStatus.Listener) - LocationManager#addGpsStatusListener(...). 
In the onGpsStatusChanged method you can react to GpsStatus#GPS_EVENT_STARTED or GpsStatus#GPS_EVENT_STOPPED and change the update of your UI via Handler. Hope this helps :-)