# Android onResume method called when activity is not visible

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I want to the access the gps service in my application.So I used `Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);` inside the `onClick()` method of a button.After calling the Intent I start the service to listen for location updates.In the onResume method I check for gps service.If it is disabled,I stop the service.But the onResume method is called when the Location Settings is shown and the service is ultimately stopped even before the user can turn on the gps.

Code:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(i);
     gps_intent=new Intent(AddOffers.this, StatsGpsService.class);
     gps_intent.putExtra("offr_act_ind",true);
     startService(gps_intent);



 @Override
     protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     boolean isproviderenabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(isproviderenabled==false){
        if(gps_intent!=null){
            Log.e("g","g");
        stopService(gps_intent);
    }}
```

StatsGpsService.java:

```
public class StatsGpsService extends Service {
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean flag1;

    public StatsGpsService() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("Service","Created");


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        handleLocation(intent);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service","Destroyed");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void handleLocation(Intent intent){
        if(intent!= null) {
            flag1 = intent.getBooleanExtra("offr_act_ind", false);

            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if (flag1 == true) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent("loc_updts");
                        intent.putExtra("stat_lat", location.getLatitude());
                        intent.putExtra("stat_longt", location.getLongitude());
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                    Log.e("Provider","Disabled");

                }
            };
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in which callback of the activity, are you starting the gps service?

Comment: I am starting it in the onClick method of the button.

Comment: My question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616956/which-activity-life-cycle-gets-called-when-app-redirect-to-settings

Comment: Why do you need a service for this? Can't you just register your location listener in activity itself and then unregister it when you receive the location?

Comment: I need live gps updates for the activity

Comment: If you need updates for single activity, you can register/unregister the listener in onStart and onStop method respectively

Comment: I want to unregister it as soon as the location is received

Comment: then what's the problem in unregistering it in activity when you receive the location?

Comment: It says receiver not registered

Comment: are you registering your listener in activity's onCreate itself?

Comment: no. in onresume() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137564/discussion-between-yashasvi-and-jobin).

Answer (score 0):

Do not check GPS status on onResume.
Use startActivityForResult to open Settings.

And check Gps Status on onActivityResult

To open setting use below code

```
Intent SettingIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
SettingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(SettingIntent,Utils.SETTING_INTENT_REQUESTCODE// any int code you can use);
```

To handle result you need to override onActivityResult method of Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Utils.SETTING_INTENT_REQUESTCODE// this should be same int that you passed to start acitivity) {
            LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean isproviderenabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(isproviderenabled==false){
                if(gps_intent!=null){
                    Log.e("g","g");
                    stopService(gps_intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: I tried using onActivityResult before but it is called when Settings is open

Comment: You might have Activity declared in Manifest with  android:launchMode="singleTop". try to change it with android:launchMode="standard" and check

Comment: The Activity from which you are starting Setting Intent

Comment: I don't know the cause than. But onAcitivityResult called prior if You have made activitylaunch mode to SingleTop. I have run through this issue and resolved it by making launchmode standard.